# How do I tell JBehave META-INF to configure it for JPA using the Maven plugin?

Tags: jpa, maven-2, maven-plugin, jbehave, jbehave-plugin

I'm trying to get JBehave, JPA and Maven to play nicely together. I can run the test via eclipse and everything works just fine. I run it via maven, and JPA can't find the `persistence.xml` file.  However a unit test I have finds the `persistence.xml` file just fine, but JBehave is not involved.

Clearly I need to tell JBehave to look in `src/main/resources` for the `META-INF/persistence.xml` file, or get it on the classpath at least. Is there a way to do that?

org.jbehave
                jbehave-maven-plugin
                2.3-rc1
                
                    
                        run-scenarios-found
                        test
                        
                            test
                            
                                test/nsfw/bmp/partymodel/PartySearch.java
                                test/nsfw/bmp/partymodel/RealtionshihpFunctionality.java
                            
                        
                        
                            run-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I checked out quickly the jbehave-maven-plugin sources and it may be classloader issue. But without more details (e.g. the plugin version you use, the phase you run, the pom.xml), the only suggestion I can do is to open an issue here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JBEHAVE/component/12482.